# la ultima tabla que contiene la llave forania no me deja crear la tabla

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

```
CREATE TABLE usuarios(
   id       int(7) unsigned AUTO_INCREMENT not null,
   nombre   varchar(100) not null,
   apellido varchar(100) not null,
   email    varchar(255) not null,
   pasword  varchar(255) not null,
   fecha    date not null,
   CONSTRAINT pk_usuarios PRIMARY KEY (id),
   CONSTRAINT uq_email UNIQUE (email)
)ENGINE=innoDB;

CREATE TABLE categorias (
   id          int(255) auto_increment not null,
   nombre      varchar(100) not null,
   CONSTRAINT pk_categorias PRIMARY KEY (id)
   ) ENGINE=innoDB;

CREATE TABLE entradas(
id int(255) auto_increment not null,
usuarioid int(255) not null,
categoriaid int(255) not null,
titulo varchar(255) not null,
fecha date not null,
CONSTRAINT pk_entradas PRIMARY KEY (id),
**constraint FK_usuario FOREIGN KEY (usuarioid) REFERENCES usuarios(id),
constraint FK_categoria FOREIGN KEY (categoriaid) REFERENCES categorias(id)
);**
```

Comment: ¿Qué error obtienes?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! mas alla de que leas todo eso, los campos tienen que ser exactamente iguales, y aca no son iguales

Comment: El error es porque tu `id` tiene como atributo `unsigned` y tu `usuarioid` no. Si le dices a MySQL que usarás solo números positivos tu clave foránea relacionada a esa tabla debe igual contenerla.

Comment: solucionado gracias cuate

Answer (score 0):

Cuando agregas una clave foránea, tienes que fijarte que los tipos de datos de las columnas coincidan exactamente, o al menos que puedan almacenar el mismo conjunto de valores.

En tu caso eso no se cumple porque la columna `id` de `usuarios` es "unsigned" y la clave foránea no lo es. En resumen la PK no es capaz de almacenar todos los valores que la clave foránea podría producir. Para resolver el problema haz que los tipos de datos sean idénticos. Por ejemplo:

```
CREATE TABLE usuarios(
   id       int AUTO_INCREMENT not null,
   nombre   varchar(100) not null,
   apellido varchar(100) not null,
   email    varchar(255) not null,
   pasword  varchar(255) not null,
   fecha    date not null,
   CONSTRAINT pk_usuarios PRIMARY KEY (id),
   CONSTRAINT uq_email UNIQUE (email)
)ENGINE=innoDB;

CREATE TABLE categorias (
   id          int auto_increment not null,
   nombre      varchar(100) not null,
   CONSTRAINT pk_categorias PRIMARY KEY (id)
   ) ENGINE=innoDB;

CREATE TABLE entradas(
  id int(255) auto_increment not null,
  usuarioid int not null,
  categoriaid int not null,
  titulo varchar(255) not null,
  fecha date not null,
  CONSTRAINT pk_entradas PRIMARY KEY (id),
  constraint FK_usuarioxx FOREIGN KEY (usuarioid) REFERENCES usuarios(id),
  constraint FK_categoria FOREIGN KEY (categoriaid) REFERENCES categorias(id)
);
```

Ejemplo que se puede ver funcionando en [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xj6XmNxWuEVZTDWcEohgmZ/0).

Comment: Ya fue respondida esta pregunta.